# html5 validation api gives an empty array of messages if a markup is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, json, validation

Trying to validate my html5 markup by clicking on a button and using the w3c validator. The code source is [from here](https://dev.to/madsstoumann/validating-markup-write-your-own-snippet-2p8d).

so my code is like this:

```
$('.btnw3').on('click', async function(){
    valid()
  .then(data => {
    console.clear();
    console.log(data); // Console was cleared - {messages: Array(0)}
        const error = data.messages.filter(msg => msg.type === 'error');
const warning = data.messages.filter(msg => msg.type === 'info' && msg?.subType === 'warning');

if (warning.length) {
  console.group(`%c${warning.length} validation warnings`, "background-color:#FFFBE5;padding:1px 4px");
  warning.forEach(msg => {
    console.groupCollapsed(`%c${msg.message} (line: ${msg.lastLine})`, "background-color:#FFFBE5");
    console.table(msg)
    console.groupEnd();
  })
  console.groupEnd();
}
if (error.length) {
  console.group(`%c${error.length} validation errors`, "background-color:#D93025;color:#FFF;padding:1px 4px");
  error.forEach(msg => {
    console.groupCollapsed(`%c${msg.message} (line: ${msg.lastLine})`, "color:#D93025");
    console.table(msg)
    console.groupEnd();
  })
  console.groupEnd();  // empty output
}
  })

});
```

so I intentionally make my markup wrong - write `</divx>` instead of `</div>` - for example

problem - I'm getting an empty array of messages on `(console.log(data))` line

the same happens if I write this code as a snippet in chrome dev tools

if I copy my markup source and paste it on `https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea` - I'm getting the expecting errors.

Comment: Problem is browser won't process `</divx>` in place of an opening `<div>` and how it handles it can be unpredictable but you will never get that invalid tag markup back from the browser innerHTML. You might catch a few things this way but it is definitely not going to be the same as giving the validator the raw source markup

Comment: I've written a lot of html over last 15 years. With IDEs being a lot better at linting than they used to be I haven't used an html validator like w3c for probably 8-10 years. Proabbly also due to using a lot more front end framworks like React, Angular etc

Comment: @charlietfl - so what is then the purpose of the validator api? It is an official w3c api - isn't it ? If this is true - `...unpredictable but you will never get that invalid tag markup back...`

Comment: Well just so I am sure my assumption is correct you are getting the html out of the document after browser has processed it is that correct? You aren't really showing how you get/send the markup. As for what good is the API you could conceivably read raw files to send to the api as one use case